In ruby how can i convert a string array into a json string of hash of hash
Input:["Gender,FirstName,LastName,UserName,Email,Age,City,Device,Coffee Quantity, Order At", "Male,Carl,Wilderman,carl,yahoo.com,21->40,Seattle,Safari iPhone,2,afternoon", "Male,Marvin,Lind,marvin,hotmail.com,66->99,Detroit,Chrome Android,2,afternoon", "Female,Shanelle,Marquardt,shanelle,hotmail.com,21->40,Las Vegas,Chrome,1,afternoon", "Female,Lavonne,Romaguera,lavonne,yahoo.com,66->99,Seattle,Chrome,2,morning", "Male,Derick,McLaughlin,derick,hotmail.com,41->65,Chicago,Chrome Android,1,afternoon"]

Output:
'{"Gender":{"Male":3,"Female":2},"Email":{"yahoo.com":2,"hotmail.com":3},"Age":{"21->40":2,"66->99":2,"41->65":1},"City":{"Seattle":2,"Detroit":1,"Las Vegas":1,"Chicago":1},"Device":{"Safari iPhone":1,"Chrome Android":2,"Chrome":2},"Order At":{"afternoon":4,"morning":1}}'

